# Inserting multiple rows in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, insert, multiple-insert

I'm trying to insert multiple rows but I continue getting an sqlerror and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

```
    echo '"'.$thequery.'"';
    $sql = mysql_query($thequery) or die(mysql_error());
    return "SUCCESS";
```

$thequery gets printed out as:
"INSERT INTO thistable (rank, change, reqID, vanID) VALUES (1,'PICKUP',28,1),(2,'PICKUP',29,1),(3,'DROPOFF',28,1),(4,'DROPOFF',29,1)"

and the error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change, reqID, vanID) VALUES (1,'PICKUP',28,1),(2,'PICKUP',29,1),(3,'DROPOFF',28' at line 1

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Justin Casing is not a reason for syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHANGE` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Rename the column or enclose the identifier in backticks.

Besides, you seem to have a typo in the `VALUES` part: in `(1,'PICKUP,'28,1),(2,'PICKUP,'29,1),`, the `,'` should be `',`.

Comment: I fixed the apostrophe error and it didn't help.
but i did change change to thistable.change and it worked, many thanks! What do you mean my backtick tho? Would it just be 'change?

Comment: No, ' is no backtick. ` is one. You would write `\`change\``.